# Is ReentrantLock is a light weight lock？

Tags: jvm, reentrantlock

As we known, HotSpot VM has bias lock, spin lock, lightweight lock, heavyweight lock and so on，and ReentrantLock is implemented by AbstractQueuedSynchronizer（AQS）。 So ReentrantLock is a light weight lock in JVM？

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are different concepts.

Spin lock, Biased lock, etc. are the names of algorithms/structures for implementing a locking mechanism (a mutex).

In HotSpot terminology, biased lock, lightweight (thin) lock and heavyweight (inflated) lock are the possible states of a Java intrinsic monitor, i.e. a Java object that you can synchronize on using a `synchronized` keyword.

In different moments of time, the same Java monitor can be in different states, e.g.

1. On the first lock attempt the object is *biased* to a certain thread.
2. Later, when another thread acquires the lock, the bias is revoked, and the monitor is successfully reacquired with a simple CAS - this will be a *thin* lock.
3. Finally, when the a different thread attempts to acquite the monitor which is already locked, the lock is *inflated*.

`ReentrantLock` is a Java class that implements the semantics of a mutex independently of Java intrinsic monitors. That is, the terms *biased*, *thin* and *inflated* do not appy to `ReentrantLock`.

At the same time, `ReentrantLock` implementation also has multiple different paths. In a simple case, when there is no contention, acquiring `ReentrantLock` is a matter of a single CAS. In the contended case, `ReentrantLock` involves the waiting queue, and calls `park` to switch current thread from `RUNNABLE` to `WAITING` state. In this sense, the mechanism resembles JVM's thin and inflated locks. But again: since `ReentrantLock` is not an instrinsic monitor, it's not quite correct to compare it with JVM's lightweight and heavyweight locks.